# Separately validate two forms of the same page in asp.net using HTML5 validation

Tags: asp.net, html, validation

I have two forms for login and registration.I am trying to use HTML5 validation. When i click the form to submit login, controls of registration is validated and vice versa.How do I prevent that? I know there is something called validation group but I guess that works only for the validationcontrols provided by .NET.

Here's my code:

```
<h2><em> Registration </em></h2>

       <asp:TextBox ID="tb_uname" class="login_mem" runat="server"  placeholder="Name" required></asp:TextBox> <br />
       <asp:TextBox ID="tb_address" class="login_mem" runat="server" placeholder="Address" ></asp:TextBox> <br />
       <asp:TextBox ID="tb_email" class="login_mem"  runat="server"  placeholder="Email" ></asp:TextBox> <br />
       <asp:TextBox ID="tb_pass"  class="login_mem" TextMode="Password"  runat="server" placeholder="Password" ></asp:TextBox> <br />

       <asp:Button ID="btn_reg" runat="server" Text="Registration" CausesValidation="false"
             onclick="btn_reg_Click"/>
     </div>

      <div id="log"> 
       <h2><em>Login </em></h2>

       <asp:TextBox ID="tb_name" class="login_mem" runat="server" placeholder="username" required></asp:TextBox> <br />

       <asp:TextBox ID="tb_password" class="login_mem" runat="server" placeholder="password"></asp:TextBox><br />

        <asp:Button ID="btn_log" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="btn_log_Click"/>
        <asp:Label ID="error" runat="server"></asp:Label>

     </div>
```

Comment: it would be helpful for us if you show us the code for `btn_reg_Click` and `btn_log_Click`. The code that you have given is just the mark up of the page, that's it.

Comment: Did you get it to work? If yes, could you please post the solution as well. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the **novalidate** tag to your forms to prevent them from validating when submitting them.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" novalidate>
```

Or you could add it to one or multiple forms using javascrit/query:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');
});
```